# 自分の小市民ぶり meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning

「―――いえ。 誰にも遠野くんは傷つけさせません。 それだけは信じてください」
……というか、そんな事より旅費とかパスポートとかを心配してしまう自分の小市民ぶりが情けない。

I cannot understand the last sentence, especially 自分の小市民ぶりが情けない。 Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

小市民 means "une Petite bourgeoisie." It used to be a word from Marxism, but I think this word completely lost its red colour.

It is a class between the landed class and the laboring class.
People in the landed class own and do not need to work.
People in the laboring class has nothing and need to work.
Unlike them, 小市民 owns a little and needs to work.
So, they really care about what they have and do not care about "great problems".
This is different from land lords trying to hold on power, and workers caring about what makes them suffer.

Back to the original text, I do not know the context, but probably they are talking about something quite serious; possibility of being harmed or killed. Yet, he worries about a passport and travel cost, which might be about thousands or hundreds dollars. This is a typical act of a 小市民.

So, "I am disgusted with myself of acting like a typical 小市民."

Comment: Why "disguised"?  Makes no sense.

Comment: ^ disguised >> disgusted の間違いでしょうね・・・

Comment: わかってまんがな。本人さんに気付いてほしくてコメしただけですねん。